# Call static method from instance in PHP, future deprecation?

Tags: php, this, static-methods, deprecated, instance-methods

While I understand the `$this` variable is not available when a method is called in a static context, to assist in decoupling my application components from one-another I figured it would make sense to call static methods from an instance. For example:

```
class MyExample{
    private static $_data = array();
    public static function setData($key, $value){
        self::$_data[$key] = $value;
    }
    // other non-static methods, using self::$_data
}

// to decouple, another class or something has been passed an instance of MyExample
// rather than calling MyExample::setData() explicitly
// however, this data is now accessible by other instances
$example->setData('some', 'data');
```

Are there plans to deprecate this sort of functionality, or am I right to expect support for this going forward? I work with `error_reporting(-1)` to ensure a very strict development environment, and there aren't any issues as of yet (*PHP 5.3.6*) however I am aware of the reverse becoming unsupported; that is, instance methods being called statically.

Comment: `$example::method()` will look for a class with the name `$example` evaluates to, so I don't believe that will work (*barring trickery with `__toString()`*) ... **or not?** I didn't expect that to work, however it appears to have. I'm curious though, syntactically (and technically) if that's the best direction.

Comment: well i hope its not going to be deprecated anytime soon... its going to break a lot of code, ha!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [Php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated 
>       class object (**though a static method can**).

So I think it will be forward-supported for a long time.

Comment: As of 2016, ["For the record, there are currently no plans, neither specific nor speculative, to deprecate this functionality."](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/3yph4q/is_it_bad_practice_to_call_a_static_method_via_an/cyg3fct/)

Comment: @bishop What about 2021?

Answer (score 4):

You can always use:

```
$class = get_class($example);
$class::setData('some', 'data');
```

If you want to be explicit about the method beeing static.

Or, from inside the class you can use the keywords self and static (and the function get_called_class) also in non static methods:

```
self::setData('some', 'data');
```

or

```
static::setData('some', 'data');
```

or

```
$class = get_called_class();
$class::setData('some', 'data');
```

- Self references the class where the method is declared: if the method is in class Animal and Parrot extends Animal, self will reefernce class Animal even if called in an object of type Parrot.
- Static references the class of the object being used (the class of $this), so if the method is in Animal and it is called on an instance of Parrot it references class Parrot (like the get_class and get_called_class functions)

So, if you are in object Parrot that extends Animal, and the followiong code is written in class Animal:

```
self::setData('some', 'data');
```

is like

```
Animal::setData('some', 'data');
```

and

```
static::setData('some', 'data');
```

is like

```
Parrot::setData('some', 'data');
```

As a suggestion I would rather make a non static method with an informative name that calls the static one, rather then get the class from outside every time. It seems to me more concise, clean and clear:

```
public function setStaticData($a,$b) {
    return static::setData($a,$b);
}
```