# Why static properties not accessible by -> but static function accessiable?

Tags: php, class, oop, static, static-methods

I have below code

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $count = 0;

    public static function plusOne()
    {
        return "The count is " . ++self::$count . ".<br />";
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->plusOne(); //Works proper for static function

echo '<br/>'.MyClass::$count; // count: 1

MyClass::plusOne(); //Works proper for static function
echo '<br/>'.MyClass::$count; // count: 2

----OUTPUT------
1
2

----------------
```

1. I have access static method by creating object (using ->) and by scope resolution operator (using ::) Method works properly
   But when I am trying to use static Property by scope resolution (using :: ) It display notice don't work. below is additional code.

   **$obj->count; // Notice: Undefined property: MyClass::$count**
2. I have access static method by creating object (using ->) and by scope resolution operator (using ::) BUT still static properties count increases WHY?
3. Why Different access rule for static property (only :: ) and method (by ->, ::)?

Comment: You can use `->` when you've instantiate a class as an object. `::` is when you want to call something by `static`. You can not access `->$count` because that is a class member, and you can access by `::` when you did not instantiate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call static method from instance in PHP, future deprecation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398658/call-static-method-from-instance-in-php-future-deprecation)

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Thanks. In Q2 I have used method 2 different(i.e. ->, :: ) but count increased at the end. first time i have used $obj->plusOne() and second time directly MyClass::plusOne() any idea?

Comment: @Darhazer: Thanks. I got my Q1 answer through your link. Could you please help me to resolve Q2 How/Why its happen?

Comment: as @lolka_bolka pointed out, using designation `->` does not mean it **has** to be a non-static method, it just has to be a method defined in the class from which an object was instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

In your example it looks odd, but imagine if you also had

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function plusOne()
    {
        return "The other count is " . ++$this->count . ".<br />";
    }
}
```

Now if you want to do

```
$obj->plusOne();
```

You can do that and it will work regardless of if $obj is MyClass or MyOtherClass. The implementation details aren't important at this point, unless you already know them - eg. you can use MyClass::plusOne() without instantiating it, because you know that's a static method.

Static variables are always static as declared. There is no data on the instance - so whatever scope you're using when you update it, it will update the static count.

Comment: Thanks But I need to know why difference in accessing static variable and static function not alternative code.

Comment: Sure, the code just intended to illustrate the point: when you access a method on a variable, that variable might not always be the same class. It might have a class where that method is static, or it might have one where it is not. Using -> you can invoke the given method in either case.